# React Router: Show progress while loading

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to show a progress bar when I switch one route from another, I found this package: [nprogress](https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress), for youtube-like progress.

My problem is implementing this using React Router. I somehow need to execute `NProgress.start();` on every start of routing, and `NProgress.done();` when loaded.

Is there a better way (like a middleware between route changes or route listener for the router), other then going thorugh each route and doing `start()` on the `onEnter`, and `done()` on the component's `DidMount()`?

Comment: How did you go about solving this?

Comment: I haven't. I ended up going throue each router and calling start and done, on onEnter and on DidMount (respectively)

Answer (score 1):

You may simply start with `NProgress.start()` in [`onEnter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback) handler and finish in [`getComponent`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#getcomponentnextstate-callback) or [`getComponents`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#getcomponentsnextstate-callback) where you can asynchronously load your component, e.g. with Webpack’s `require.ensure`.

Something like this:

```
  <Route
    path="path"
    onEnter={() => {
      NProgress.start();
    }}
    getComponent={(nextState, cb) => {
      require.ensure([], (require) => {
        const Component = require('./path/to/Component').default;
        cb(null, Component);
        NProgress.done();
      });
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `react-redux-loading-bar` and dispatching necessary action in every and every route definition:

```
import {ROUTE_CHANGE_END, ROUTE_CHANGE_START} from 'redux/constants';

export default (store) => ({
  path: 'register',
  /*  Async getComponent is only invoked when route matches   */
  getComponent (nextState, cb) {
    store.dispatch({type: ROUTE_CHANGE_START});
    /*  Webpack - use 'require.ensure' to create a split point
        and embed an async module loader (jsonp) when bundling   */
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      /*  Webpack - use require callback to define
          dependencies for bundling   */
      const Register = require('./containers/RegisterContainer').default;
      const reducer = require('./modules/Register').default;

      /*  Add the reducer to the store on key 'counter'  */
      injectReducer(store, { key: 'register', reducer });

      store.dispatch({type: ROUTE_CHANGE_END});

      /*  Return getComponent   */
      cb(null, Register);

    /* Webpack named bundle   */
    }, 'Register');
  }
});
```